# Selenium: chrome version must be >= 62 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: selenium, raspberry-pi, chromium, raspbian

I tried to let a python selenium script run on my raspberry pi. I use the selenium package for that. As I gonna run the script I get the following error:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chr, chrome_options=options)
[...]
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: 
Message: session not created exception: 
Chrome version must be >= 62.0.3202.0 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35 (0), platform=Linux 4.9.35-v7+ armv71)
```

As I open the Chromium browser I see, that the current version is 56.0.2924.84 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on Raspbian 8.0. Every attempt to update the current packages with `apt get update/upgrade´ did not update the browser.

I checked similar topics, but all that was mentioned there did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific reason for running on old Raspbian distro?

I'd recommend updating to current stable Pi OS (new name for Raspbian), which ships with newer Chromium versions.

Current Pi OS, 2020-08-20, is based on Debian 10 Buster and chips with Chromium 83.